# Scope sharing between controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have some weird behavior on a simple scope variable that do not enter into the watcher when i change its content :

```
$scope.test = "test";
$scope.$watch('test', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("watcher=>"+newVal);
});
```

but when i pass an object it works :

```
$scope.test = {title: "test"};
$scope.$watch('test.title', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("watcher=>"+newVal);
});
```

I'm unable to reproduce this behavior on a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pvYSu/33/

EDIT :

I reproduced my problem in this fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/pvYSu/34/
I think it's related with a bad use on Angular so if someone can find and explain me what i've missed ;)

Comment: the two ways of defining the controller should be interchangeable, so I would search for a problem elsewhere

Comment: I think so but i dont have any more clue...

Comment: I think the reason is you didn't use third parameter inside `$watch`... since it is object you are watching, you have to use `$scope.$watch('test', function (newVal, oldVal) {...}, true);`

Comment: I'm stupid, I didn't see the first one has a different `$scope.test`...

Comment: No problem ;) so it's weird that it's the second that works and not the first one.

Comment: not really, because in the second one you are watching directly the attribute

Comment: I have edited my question to add a fiddle that show my problem

Comment: the approach is wrong. You are using isolated scope, but watching for changes outside of that scope... and also what is the expected behavior? You want the address in the directive to change when you type different name?

Comment: I'm not using this code but it demonstrate the problem i have. What i need to do is making a directive that can change the properties in an array passed in arguments like info in this test and that can be applied in the controller scope. So if i'm not using the correct approch, how can i do this?

Comment: generally, for communication and data manipulation between controller and directive, you should use a service

Comment: are there not an easier way to do this?

Comment: yeah I do not agree. Directives can achieve communication with a controller in various different ways without the use of services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you had to do was to use `ng-model` in the directive's template and it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvYSu/35/

```js
<div>
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="customerInfo.name" />
    Address: {{customerInfo.address}}
</div>
```

You also do not actually need an isolated scope for this.

http://jsfiddle.net/pvYSu/36/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found how to solve my other problem but i still can't understand why it's not working... it works with an object but with a literal the watcher is never fired.